Shorter error message for rails exception
I am rescuing an error like
undefined local variable or method 'something' for #<PdfHelper::MyPdfHelper...................@stream="\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00........................"
the @stream here is basically storing a whole raw pdf data, due to which the error message is very very long. I need to save this error message to a record but in a shorter way, is there any good way to do this instead of just truncating the message to a few characters?
I have tried truncating it to few hundred characters only, but looking for a better way.

You could override the inspect method on that object to only include the values you are interested in.
